# Is there a restriction which prevents you from creating a user and a role with the same name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, authentication

I have a (SS2005) database with a user named MY_APPLICATION_USER. I'm trying to create a role in that database named MY_APPLICATION_USER.

When I try to do that using this script:

```
/****** Object:  Role [MY_APPLICATION_USER] ******/
CREATE ROLE [MY_APPLICATION_USER] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
```

I get the error message:

```
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
User, group, or role 'MY_APPLICATION_USER' already exists in the current database.
```

Does SQL Server have a restriction where it is not allowed to have a user and a role with the same name? I googled various ways of asking that question and did not find anything which addresses this, but it's certainly possible that I missed something.

Comment: The error states it rather well:  You cannot have a user and role with the same name.  They all fall under `sys.database_principals`.

Comment: I figured that was it but I couldn't find any documentation confirming it. Please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  I didn't know where it stores that information  and I just assumed roles would be stored separate from the users but now I know better.

Comment: Note this makes perfect sense: otherwise, how can you resolve SomePrincipal in this `GRANT .. TO SomePrincipal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have a User and a Role with the same name.  These objects are all stored and referenced in `sys.database_principals`, requiring they are unique.

[sys.database_principals MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx)

Quoted from the `name` parameter:

> **name** : Name of principal, unique within the database.